# Start a thread in a loop

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, loops

I wonder know how to start a thread for the 1st time in a loop :

Example:

```
while(something)
{

 /*
 ...
 Some codes
 ...
 */

   thread.start();
}
```

The problem is that I get this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.
```

..because it's restart the thread every time in the loop...

How to start the thread only 1 time in the loop?

Comment: Why not just start the thread before/after the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a boolean value to tell you when the value is set in order to set it once. I don't know why you can't set it outside of the loop but something like this should work if I'm understanding correctly.

```
boolean started = false;

while(something){
    if(!started){
        thread.start();
        started = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
while(something)
{

 /*
 ...
 Some codes
 ...
 */
   if (!thread.isAlive()) {
     thread.start();
   }
}
```

Comment: It's still give me the error because The thread die and it's restart likes said @johnchen902

Answer (score 3):

You can check a thread's state by `getState()`

```
while(something){
    /* ... */

    if (thread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW) {
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for a solution that doesn't cause trouble if the thread dies.

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways could be using the `isAlive()` method -

```
while(something)
{

/*
...
Some codes
...
*/
 if(!thread.isAlive()) {
   thread.start();
 }
```

}